# How to modify Cookie from Ajax call

Tags: javascript, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I have this code:

```
window.onload = function() {
        document.cookie = 'foo=bar; expires=Sun, 01 Jan 2012 00:00:00 +0100; path=/';
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "/showcookie.php",true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "foo=quux");

        xhr.setRequestHeader("Foo", "Bar");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Foo", "Baz");

        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        var pre = document.getElementById('output');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (4 == xhr.readyState) {
                pre.innerHTML += xhr.responseText + "\n";
            }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    };
```

and this /showcookie.php

```
<?php

print_r($_COOKIE);

?>
```

and it always show

```
Array
(
    [Host] => localhost
    [User-Agent] => 
    [Accept] => 
    [Accept-Language] => pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip,deflate
    [Accept-Charset] => ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    [Keep-Alive] => 115
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [foo] => Baz
    [Referer] =>
    [Cookie] => foo=bar
)

Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)
```

I'm using Firefox 3.6.13, Opera 11.00 and Chromium 9.0 on Ubuntu.

Is anybody have the same problem or maybe it's impossible to modify Cookie header.

Comment: If you weren't using 1.5 I wouldn't be surprised, since the jqXHR docs specifically say `setRequestHeader(name, value) which departs from the standard by replacing the old value with the new one rather than concatenating the new value to the old one`, implying that the old way was to simply concatenate the value - but in 1.5 that should have changed.

Comment: So why it don't remove the cookie value from the headers? when I call `xhr.setRequestHeader('Foo', 'Bar'); xhr.setRequestHeader('Foo', 'Baz');` it send `Foo:Baz` as expected but for unknown reason it don't change the Cookie header.

Comment: @jcubic - if you were using anything before jQuery 1.5 (maybe check to make sure you are including the jquery version you think you are?), it would [in some browsers](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/b85d086af78be791?pli=1) concatenate "" to the Cookies header value with that call.  With 1.5 it is *supposed* to replace the Cookies header value with "".

Comment: I change the question because the I got the same with pure XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: does the cookie by any chance get set to http only somewhere ? i doubt that is the case but just my thought of what to check ...

Comment: Cookie are setting with first line `document.cookie = ...` and when I run the code and then remove that line and run it again, the cookies are still there.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Cookie header is one of several which cannot be modified in an `XMLHttpRequest`. From the [specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name):

> Terminate *[execution of the `setRequestHeader` method]* if header is a
>   case-insensitive match for one of the
>   following headers:
>
> - Accept-Charset
> - Accept-Encoding
> - Connection
> - Content-Length
> - Cookie
> - Cookie2
> - Content-Transfer-Encoding
> - Date
> - Expect
> - Host
> - Keep-Alive
> - Referer
> - TE
> - Trailer
> - Transfer-Encoding
> - Upgrade
> - User-Agent
> - Via
>
> … or if the start of header is a
>   case-insensitive match for Proxy- or
>   Sec- (including when header is just
>   Proxy- or Sec-).
>
> The above headers are controlled by
>   the user agent to let it control those
>   aspects of transport. This guarantees
>   data integrity to some extent. Header
>   names starting with Sec- are not
>   allowed to be set to allow new headers
>   to be minted that are guaranteed not
>   to come from XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to know, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this might be a hard constraint on the XHR functionality.

Setting the clientside document.cookie caused the Cookie header to be sent in requests as expected. If you want to pass a cookie value in an an ajax request this might be the way to go.

A workaround is to send a custom header to the php script with the cookie string you want to set:

```
// in the js...
xhr.open("GET", "showcookie.php",true);
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "foo=quux");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Set-Cookie", "foo2=quux");

xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

Then in your showcookie.php you can grab the custom header value and fire a set-cookie response header:

```
$cookie = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SET_COOKIE'];

// NOTE: really should sanitise the cookie input.
header('Set-Cookie: ' . $cookie);


print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Note that you wont see a cookie header until the response is parsed by the browser. Also please make sure you sanitise the contents of the X_SET_COOKIE header - this is a proof of concept only:)

Comment: This is the same if I put variables in query string `showcookie.php?foo=quux` or use `POST` and I don't want to get the value for new `foo` in custom header but change real `Cookie` header, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, of course, no problem. You could just update the 'foo' value set in document.cookie, it gets sent in xhr request.