# cant set cookie?

Tags: php, cookies

I am using

```
public function setCookie() {
  $value = $this->info('id').':'.$this->info('salt');
  //$value == '1:0842d579c6c9f08401d7204240d06930'
  $expire = (time()+((3600*24)*365));
  return setcookie("remember", $value, $expire);
}
```

and it is returning true,

but when i print out `$_COOKIE` on the next page the only cookie set is the php sess id.

Why is it not setting?

---

**Notes**
The page that sets the cookie is requested through ajax.
The current page/ajax'd page/next page are all on the same domain name
Nothing is sent before the cookie is  set

Comment: What is the current page and the next page? Maybe the cookie is not valid for the next page.

Comment: Have you sent anything before the cookie?

Comment: try to check `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` array, another possibility is that you call this function after headers are send and you have disabled all warnings.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077998/how-to-modify-cookie-from-ajax-call/5123282#5123282

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> bool setcookie ( string $name [,
>   string $value [, int $expire = 0 [,
>   string $path [, string $domain [, bool
>   $secure = false [, bool $httponly =
>   false ]]]]]] )

From the [`setcookie`](http://www.php.net/setcookie) man page.

Try setting the domain and path values as well and see if that works, IE:

```
setcookie("remember", $value, $expire, '.domain.com', '/');
```

---

*Edit*

If you are working localhost here is more information on it:

Source: http://www.aeonity.com/frost/php-setcookie-localhost-apache

```
setcookie("username", "George", false, "/", false);
```

You would use that version. I am not entirely sure why that is required for localhost to work. A better method would be to setup a virtual-host in apache and then modify your `hosts` file to add what you set the `ServerName` of the vhost to. This will avoid you having to modify your `setcookie` function to coax it into working, so when you push to staging/production, you don't have to worry about the hack-arounds.

Comment: @Hailwood I would use some type of cookie inspector on the browser and check it out. Granted, I never tried to set a cookie with AJAX, and that could be your undoing. I would write up a simple script in PHP and call that page on its own and test if cookies set. If it does, its the whole ajax mess, IE AJAX is sending a request to the server, and since the browser is not the one interacting with that page, the cookie never gets set. Possible solution, use javascript to set the cookie. Another way, use `SESSION` and check that on the next page load and set the cookie if that variable is present.

Comment: actually, I think you are onto something, after inspecting the cookie it is getting set, but its path is 'ajax/login' so I tried doing `'localhost', '/'` but then the cookie doesnt even get set at all :/

Comment: Right, given it is an AJAX request, the cookie will not be set on the client side, as the xml request is like a whole new user requesting that page. So yea, either set the cookie with javascript, or set a `session` variable that you can check on the next page load the user makes, if that variable is present / true then set a cookie for 'remember'.  For a better explanation of why, see jcubic's response in the comments above.

Comment: for some reason setting the path/ domain to `"/", false);` works, why is that?

Comment: Are you working on a local development box using `localhost` ? Edited the above with an explanation.