# passing headers with ajax in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with passing headers in ajax call on jquery.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/resources/ajax/customize.aspx?' + qs + '&nocache=' + Math.random(),
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: values,
    context: $this,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
          //do stuff here
    }
});
```

In most cases, it gets the headers values right, but sometimes it doesn't get any headers value. I made sure that 'values' variable contains data. I was wondering is there any specific cases that headers don't pass in ajax?

**Update:**
I tried it as:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: '/resources/ajax/customize.aspx?' + qs + '&nocache=' + Math.random(),
     contentType: "application/json",
     beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('values',values); },
     //headers: values,
     context: $this,
     cache: false,
     success: function(data) {
                  //do stuff here
     }
 });
```

and there is no luck with that.

**Update 2**

Figured out the problem. There was a URL variable with line breaks in it, so line breaks caused headers not to be passed.

Comment: Why are you passing a `nocache` parameter if you're already adding `cache: false`?

Comment: What headers are you passing on? Is it browser-specific? Maby http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433556/jquery-jsonp-ajax-authentication-header-not-being-set helps?

Comment: probably a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call) question?

Comment: There is list of headers that can't be set or changed using ajax call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077998/how-to-modify-cookie-from-ajax-call#5123282

Comment: @Blender just to prevent browser caching.

Comment: @IvovanBeek they are just the variables that i need to pass to do some stuff on back-end.

Comment: @jcubic i am not trying to set or change any browser headers, i am just passing my data through headers. In most cases it works properly.

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz: Show us the cases (i.e. the value of the `values` variable) where it does not work!

Comment: These are the values i am passing in. Only thing changes from call to call is values of the tags

Here is the image: http://tinypic.com/r/ev9r9c/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. Got rid of the line breaks by using jquery's(or do it in JS otherwise) $.trim() method. In my case I knew that \n\r won't be a part of the value legally. this has to be checked for trim to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i have resolved it long time ago. You are right, it was all about the line breaks. As soon as you remove them, it worked fine.