# How to set Cookie into DOM

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, asp.net-web-api, jwt

Let me first discuss the whole story:
I have an WebAPI which contains login method and where I am creating jwt token and creating a cookie. Login action:

```
var token = _accountService.GetJWTToken(user);
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();

var apiCookie = new CookieHeaderValue("jwttoken", token)
    {
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(10),
        Domain = "localhost",
        HttpOnly = true,
        Path = "/"
    };

resp.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { apiCookie });
return resp;
```

I want subsequent requests to the API should contain the cookie so I can validate via ActionFilterAttribute. Though I can see the cookie in the response, but it's not being added into the DOM. Am I missing something?

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var cookie = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[RoleSettings.JWTCookieName];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        var token = _accountService.DecodeJWTToken(cookie.Value);
        context.RouteData.Values.Add("userId", token["userid"]);
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Result =
                new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new {Controller = "Account", Action = "Login"}));
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I want to have the cookie with the subsequent calls. How can I achieve that? I can see the cookie is coming with the response, but document.cookie doesn't contain the jwt cookie.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't modify cookies from ajax call [How to modify Cookie from Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077998/how-to-modify-cookie-from-ajax-call)

Comment: I want to have the cookie with the subsequent calls. How can I achieve that? I can see the cookie is coming with the response, but document.cookie doesn't contain the jwt cookie,

Comment: You cannot access cookies flagged with `HttpOnly` in JavaScript. That's why `HttpOnly` exists. Also, are your Web API and your client (SPA perhaps?) in the same domain?

Comment: I tried giving HttpOnly false as well. client is SPA and they are something like api.mysite.com and app.mysite.com

Comment: Why are you trying to set the cookie on the DOM?  Setting the cookie on the server should cause the browser to return the cookie on all future calls.  Is the API a different host?